# Can a client id for authorization be generated for pages hosted on Google Drive itself?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

To authorize the Google Drive SDK one needs to provide the domain to generate the client ID. So is there a way to use it for a file hosted on Google Drive itself? The issue is that the URLs are of the form:

ce262d ... 53c2.googledrive.com/host/0B0taMM ... RQaTg/

where each hosted page has a different domain (presumably for security reasons). So can one use the realtime API without hosting the files somewhere else?

I can use the Google Drive SDK to create web pages (https://developers.google.com/drive/web/publish-site) but how can those pages make use of the realtime API?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use a hosted file in Drive to generate the Client ID, since this is always hosted as either a subdomain or an address within www.googleapis.com/drive/.

To get a Client ID, you will have to enter a valid domain origin, containing only http://yourDomain.com

Refer to the following link for further assistance: https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingoauth2

Comment: Thanks. That is what I feared. It is too bad. I can use dl.dropboxusercontent.com as a domain as well as http://toontalk.github.io/ but it looks like with Google Drive it isn't possible.